# How can I reorder a list?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

Given an arbitrary array of size `n`, I'd like to reorganize the elements of the array based on the array's discrete indices.

Python example:

```py
# Unique array of size n
[ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", ... <n> ]

# Indices of array
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... <index_of_n> ]

# Desired re-organization function 'indexMove'
indexMove(
    [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", ... <n> ],
    [ <index_of_n>, 4, 0, 2, 3, ... 1 ]
)

# Desired output from indexMove operation
[ <n>, "e", "a", "c", "d", ... "b" ]
```

What is the fastest way to perform this operation (achieving the smallest time complexity)?

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects-in-python

Comment: Without specifying *how* you want to order the items its hard to answer. Do you want to sort them? Shuffle them? Remove some of them?

Comment: @tvanfosson: In this case, arbitrary could also mean: take an arbitrary (but well defined) sort function.

Comment: @mizipzor I want to re-order them in a predefined way. (Edited the question to clarify this)

Comment: @SilentGhost It will have a new index. May be 4. The point is that I know the new order of the items.

Comment: @Niyaz -- wow -- here I am defending your question wording as being adequate to describe your problem and it turns out that your question doesn't even reflect what you are trying to do.  It seems that both you and @mizipzor are in desperate need of a dictionary.

Comment: @hop: Occam razor never fails anyone. It just requires proper use of language as an input, cf. Wittgenstein

Comment: Hmm.. I voted to close this question as *needing details or clarity*. Not sure why other reviewers overruled it with the *needing debugging details* reason. In any case, it's unclear what the "predefined manner" means in this question. There can be multiple ways to define how one wants to reorder the list: e.g. using a mapping (dict) of indices, using a list, tuples, or some mapping function to sort the list with. This ambiguity led to such different approaches in the answers.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
myorder = [3, 2, 0, 1, 4]
mylist = [mylist[i] for i in myorder]
print(mylist)         # prints: ['d', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'e']
```

Comment: This creates a new variable. How to re-order a list in-place? Thanks

Comment: @Confounded Simply change the final line to: `mylist[:] = [mylist[i] for i in myorder]`

Comment: @Adam Thanks! What's the time and space complexity of this operation?
Does it iterate over `mylist` when assigning entries from `[mylist[i] for i in myorder]` to `mylist[:]`?

Comment: Hey, I am new to Python and I am curious how does this line of code "[mylist[i] for i in myorder]" work? I have only learnt the basic for loop.

Comment: Wow, oldie but a goodie.  Thanks for taking me back @ZionAdams.  Check out List Comprehensions:  https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/#using-list-comprehensions

Answer (score 25):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a[0], a[2] = a[2], a[0]
>>> a
[3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: I just could not understand the syntax until I realized is a [pairwise simultaneous assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725673/multiple-assignment-and-evaluation-order-in-python). ´:-)

Answer (score 16):

```
>>> import random
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> random.shuffle(x)
>>> x
[5, 2, 4, 3, 1]
```

Comment: @wenlibin02, just ran it under 2.7.5 and it still works just fine.  Do you get some sort of error?

Comment: no error, I just type: 1) import random; x = [1, 2, 3]; random.shuffle(x); #it returns None; and 2) I tried np.random.shuffle. the results are the same.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I did not realize that I directly change the value of x. It did return None. And it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Is the final order defined by a list of indices ?

```
>>> items = [1, None, "chicken", int]
>>> order = [3, 0, 1, 2]

>>> ordered_list = [items[i] for i in order]
>>> ordered_list
[<type 'int'>, 1, None, 'chicken']
```

edit: meh. AJ was faster... [How can I reorder a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177590/how-can-i-reorder-a-list-in-python/2177607#2177607)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a=["a","b","c","d","e"]
>>> a[0],a[3] = a[3],a[0]
>>> a
['d', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'e']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can provide your own sort function to [`list.sort()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

> The sort() method takes optional arguments for controlling the comparisons.
>
> - *cmp* specifies a custom comparison function of two arguments (list items) which should return a negative, zero or positive number depending on whether the first argument is considered smaller than, equal to, or larger than the second argument: `cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(x.lower(), y.lower())`. The default value is `None`.
> - *key* specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element: `key=str.lower`. The default value is `None`.
> - *reverse* is a boolean value. If set to True, then the list elements are sorted as if each comparison were reversed.
>
> In general, the key and reverse conversion processes are much faster than specifying an equivalent cmp function. This is because cmp is called multiple times for each list element while key and reverse touch each element only once.

Comment: and how exactly you'd implement this?

Comment: @SilentGhost: This is meant as a general answer. In the OPs case your answer is more appropriate. Nevertheless I think it is important to know that a generic solution exists.

Answer (score 3):

If you use numpy there's a neat way to do it:

```
items = np.array(["a","b","c","d"])
indices = np.arange(items.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(indices)
print(indices)
print(items[indices])
```

This code returns:

```
[1 3 2 0]
['b' 'd' 'c' 'a']
```

Comment: OP is looking for a specific reordering, not a generic shuffling.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not care so much about efficiency, you could rely on numpy's array indexing to make it elegant:

```
a = ['123', 'abc', 456]
order = [2, 0, 1]
a2 = list( np.array(a, dtype=object)[order] )
```

Answer (score 2):

One more thing which can be considered is the other interpretation as pointed out by darkless

Code in Python 2.7

Mainly:

1. Reorder by value - Already solved by AJ above
2. Reorder by index

   ```
   mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
   myorder = [3, 2, 0, 1, 4]

   mylist = sorted(zip(mylist, myorder), key=lambda x: x[1])
   print [item[0] for item in mylist]
   ```

This will print ['c', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'e']

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your question, it appears that you want to apply a permutation that you specify on a `list`. This is done by specifying another `list` (lets call it `p`) that holds the indices of the elements of the original `list` that should appear in the permuted `list`. You then use `p` to make a new `list` by simply substituting the element at each position by that whose index is in that position in `p`.

```
def apply_permutation(lst, p):
    return [lst[x] for x in p]

arr=list("abcde")
new_order=[3,2,0,1,4]

print apply_permutation(arr,new_order)
```

This prints `['d', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'e']`.

This actually creates a new `list`, but it can be trivially modified to permute the original "in place".

Answer (score 0):

```
newList = [oldList[3]]
newList.extend(oldList[:3])
newList.extend(oldList[4:])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used when I stumbled upon this problem.

```
def order(list_item, i): # reorder at index i
    order_at = list_item.index(i)
    ordered_list = list_item[order_at:] + list_item[:order_at]
    return ordered_list
```

EX: for the the lowercase letters

```
order(string.ascii_lowercase, 'h'):
>>> 'hijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefg'
```

It simply just shifts the list to a specified index