# Looking for a function that swaps items in a list

Tags: python

I am writing a script to swap several items in some lists read from a *.txt file, I tried to write it like this:

```
i_file = map(lambda x: x.split('|'), open('test.txt', 'r').readlines())
for list in i_file:
    list = [list[2], list[0], list[3], list[1], list[4:]]
    #Actually I want to update the i_file, but I don't think this will work here
    #nevermind, it's just a demostration.
```

It looks so ugly and hard to read, so I am looking for

```
 somefunc()
```

that might make my code look like this.

```
i_file = map(lambda x: x.split('|').somefunc(), open('test.txt', 'r').readlines())
```

Thanks!!

UPDATE:

input file looks like this:

```
blahblah1|3141593|Wednesday|John|BlahBlah1|
blahblah2|2714323|Monday|Mike|BlahBlah2|
```

I want to swap these items in each line in order to rewrite the file into:

```
3141593|Wednesday|blahblah1|John|BlahBlah1|
blahblah2|Monday|2714323|Mike|BlahBlah2|
```

Comment: Please post some sample input and describe how the items should be joined in the output.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177590/how-can-i-reorder-a-list-in-python

Comment: @sleeplessnerd I can understand this method, but I am trying to avoid loops you see... Or I have to write it in two lines? thx~

Comment: Your actual wanted output is confusing: the first line swaps to: `[l[1], l[2], l[0]] + l[3:]` and the second to `[l[0], l[2], l[1]] + l[3:]`. Is that what you really want?

Comment: @Rik Poggi It's just a demo, the actual file contains more items.

Comment: @7O'clock I think Rik means it isn't clear what transformation you want to make to each line. You're showing two different transforms. Do you intend to do a different thing for each line in the file?

Comment: `list` is a poor choice of variable name, as it hides the builtin reference to the class itself.

Comment: If your goal is really just to produce the output line (a modified string with '|') and you don't need the list for anything, you might consider just using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on a one-liner using `lambda` and `map`:

```
map(lambda x: (lambda a,b,c,d,*e: list((c,a,d,b) + e))(*x.split('|')), open('test.txt', 'r').readlines())
```

Answer (score 3):

Python allows you to assign to a list slice, so you can cleanly permute the columns in-place without messing with `lambda` and `map`:

```
out = open("testout.txt", "w")

for line in open('test.txt', 'r').readlines():
    lst = line.split("|")
    lst[0:4] = lst[2], lst[0], lst[3], lst[1]
    out.write("|".join(lst))
```

You can even insert or delete columns by having more elements on one side of the assignment:

```
>>> lst = "blahblah1|3141593|Wednesday|John|BlahBlah1|\n".split("|")
>>> lst[0:4] = lst[2], lst[2][:3], lst[0], lst[3], lst[1]
>>> print "|".join(lst)
Wednesday|Wed|blahblah1|John|3141593|BlahBlah1|
```

Answer (score 2):

One general approach is to separate the indices and the list:

```
>>> parts = range(7)
>>> indices = [2, 0, 3, 1] + range(4, 7)
>>> [parts[i] for i in indices]
[2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do the following:

```
i_file = map(lambda x: x.split('|'), open('test.txt', 'r').readlines())
for l in i_file:
    l[:] = [l[2], l[0], l[3], l[1]] + l[4:]
```

Notes:

1. Thanks to the added `[:]`, this code will update `i_file`.
2. I've renamed `list` so that it doesn't shadow the [builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list).
3. I've fixed a bug in the original code whereby `l[4:]` was made into a sub-list.

Comment: thanks, although it didn't make the code into one line, this surely solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack a list into separate values then reconstitute in a different order:

```
>>> a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [a, c, b]
[1, 3, 2]
```

So for your code:

```
>>> line = 'blahblah1|3141593|Wednesday|John|BlahBlah1|'
>>> blah, number, day, name, other_name, empty = line.split('|')
>>> '|'.join([number, day, blah, name, other_name, empty])
'3141593|Wednesday|blahblah1|John|BlahBlah1|'
```

Or you could use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> line = 'blahblah1|3141593|Wednesday|John|BlahBlah1|'
>>> match = re.match(r'(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|', line)
>>> match.expand(r'\2|\3|\1|\4|\5|')
'3141593|Wednesday|blahblah1|John|BlahBlah1|'
```

Note: I'm not an expert with `re`, and there may be better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The function to do what you want is `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> lines = ["blahblah1|3141593|Wednesday|John|BlahBlah1|",
...          "blahblah2|2714323|Monday|Mike|BlahBlah2|"]
>>> swap = operator.itemgetter(2, 0, 3, 1, slice(4,None))
>>> map(lambda x: swap(x.split('|')), lines)
[('Wednesday', 'blahblah1', 'John', '3141593', ['BlahBlah1', '']), ('Monday', 'b
lahblah2', 'Mike', '2714323', ['BlahBlah2', ''])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest list comprehensions to get what you want. Something like this should do the trick. (untested)

```
i_file = [ [ y[2], y[0], y[3], y[1] ] + y[4:] for y in [ x.split('|') for x in open('test.txt','r').readlines() ] ]
```