# Rearrange a 36 bit number?

Tags: python, encode

I am an amateur to Python, I have made a program that will encode a long string of characters and output 6 characters.

```
def token (n):
    if n < 10:
        return chr( ord( '0' ) + (n) )
    if n in range (10, 36):
        return chr( ord( 'A' ) - 10 + (n))
    if n in range (37, 62):
        return chr( ord( 'a' ) - 36 + (n))
    if n is 62:
        return '-'
    if n is 63:
        return '+'
```

The token turns a number(n) into a character. Upper and lower case letters including the characters "-" and "+".

```
def encode (n):
    a = n // 1 % 64
    b = n // 64 % 64
    c = n // 64 ** 2 % 64
    d = n // 64 ** 3 % 64
    e = n // 64 ** 4 % 64
    f = n // 64 ** 5 % 64
    return (token(a) + token(b) + token(c) + token(d) + token(e) + token(f))
```

This is the rest of the encode.

```
print(encode(1234567890))
'IBWb91'
```

Again, is there a way to create an order for the six characters for the output?

This is what I have so far. I got this from an existing question.

[How can I reorder a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177590/how-can-i-reorder-a-list-in-python)

```
mylist = ['a','b','c','d','e','f',]
myorder = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
mylist = [ mylist[i] for i in myorder]
```

But...it gives me this:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What I want to happen:

```
>>> print(mylist)
['f','e','d','c','b','a']
```

I am totally new to this. Please help :)

Comment: Are you just trying to reverse the list, or do you need something more complicated?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to reverse the list, just call the `reverse` method or `reversed` function:

```
>>> mylist = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
>>> list(reversed(mylist))
['f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

If you want to do it the hard way, you can, but you have to use indices that are actually in the list:

```
>>> [i for i, e in enumerate(mylist)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Those are the indices in the list. 6 is not one of them. So if you try to use `mylist[6]` you're going to get an `IndexError`. What you probably wanted was `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Lists in python are indexed starting from `0`, not from `1`. If you want to reorder an `n`-element list with the method you show, you therefore need to have a list containing the numbers `0,1,...,n - 1`, as trying to access element `n` of an `n`-element list will give an
error, as the index will be outside of the expected range.

For example, with what you gave,

```
mylist = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
myorder = [5,4,3,2,1,0]
mylist = [mylist[i] for i in myorder]
```

Answer (score 1):

The order has to be zero-indexed. That's how python lists work - the first element is `mylist[0]`, the second element is `mylist[1]`, etc. Therefore, it should be `[5,4,3,2,1,0]`.