# Generating a new order for a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list of lists that I want to re-order:

```
qvalues = [[0.1, 0.3, 0.6],[0.7, 0.1, 0.2],[0.3, 0.4, 0.3],[0.1, 0.3, 0.6],[0.1, 0.3, 0.6],[0.1, 0.3, 0.6]]
```

I know how to reorder this list if I have a list with the order I want (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177590/how-can-i-reorder-a-list-in-python)). The tricky part is getting this order.

What I have is this:

```
locations = [(['Loc1','Loc1'], 3), (['Loc2'], 1), (['Loc3', 'Loc3', 'Loc3'], 2)]
```

This is a list of tuples, where the first element of each tuple is a list with the location name, repeated for each individual in that location, and the second element is the order these individuals are in on the `qvalues` list (`qvalues[0]` is `'Loc2'`, `qvalues[1:4]` are `'Loc3'` and `qvalues[4:6]` are `'Loc1'`.

What I want is to change the order of the lists in `qvalues` to the order they show up in `locations`: First `'Loc1'`, then `'Loc2'` and finally `'Loc3'`.

This is just a small example, my real dataset has hundreds of individuals and 17 locations.

Thanks in advance for any help you may provide.

Comment: what is the relation between the two lists? I don't see anything that is common in both lists

Comment: Sorry it was not clear. Each element of `qvalues` corresponds to a `'LocX'`. There are six elements in `qvalues`, and six `'LocX'` elements.

Comment: Your explanation of the locations list is cryptic, try to give examples of inputs and corresponding outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to build a list of offsets and length instead of length and positions as provided in your `locations` list. Then, you’ll be able to reorder based on the answer you linked to:

```
qvalues = [[0.1, 0.3, 0.6],[0.7, 0.1, 0.2],[0.3, 0.4, 0.3],[0.1, 0.3, 0.6],[0.1, 0.3, 0.6],[0.1, 0.3, 0.6]]
locations = [(['Loc1','Loc1'], 3), (['Loc2'], 1), (['Loc3', 'Loc3', 'Loc3'], 2)]

locations_dict = {pos:(index,len(loc)) for index,(loc,pos) in enumerate(locations)}
# if python2: locations_dict = dict([(pos,(index,len(loc))) for index,(loc,pos) in enumerate(locations)])

offsets = [None]*len(locations)

def compute_offset(pos):
    # compute new offset from offset and length of previous position. End of recursion at position 1: we’re at the beginning of the list
    offset = sum(compute_offset(pos-1)) if pos > 1 else 0
    # get index at where to store current offset + length of current location
    index, length = locations_dict[pos]
    offsets[index] = (offset, length)

    return offsets[index]

compute_offset(len(locations))

qvalues = [qvalues[offset:offset+length] for offset,length in offsets]
```

You’ll end up with `qvalues` being a list of lists of lists instead of a "simple" list of lists. If you want to flatten it to keep your initial layout use this list comprehension instead:

```
qvalues = [value for offset,length in offsets for value in qvalues[offset:offset+length]]
```

---

Output with first version

```
[[[0.1, 0.3, 0.6], [0.1, 0.3, 0.6]], [[0.1, 0.3, 0.6]], [[0.7, 0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4, 0.3], [0.1, 0.3, 0.6]]]
```

Output with second version

```
[[0.1, 0.3, 0.6], [0.1, 0.3, 0.6], [0.1, 0.3, 0.6], [0.7, 0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4, 0.3], [0.1, 0.3, 0.6]]
```

Comment: The output is the same as the qvalues input list?

Comment: @kezzos whoops, wasn't even paying attention to what I was computing. Actually building the `offsets` list as per the OP requirements now.