# How to I blit an Image to the front of the other images?

Tags: python, pygame

boltAnim.blit(winsurface, (pos[0]-50,pos[1]-100)??)

I am wondering how I can blit an image to front to the other images, I understand whatever I blit last will be shown last, but how can I set the blit parameters to send the image forwards or backward on the surface?

Comment: There is no Z order parameter in 2D.  Just blit them in the order you want back to front.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the order in which the images are blited on the surface/screen.

Example:

```
screen.blit("dot1")
screen.blit("dot2")
```

This will show dot2 on top of dot1.

```
screen.blit("dot2")
screen.blit("dot1")
```

This will show dot1 on top of dot2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a way to change the order of items blitted on the fly you can populate a list with images and iterate over the list to draw them all.
When you want to move something forward or back, change its order in the list

e.g:

```
items_to_be_drawn = [background,image1,image2]
for item in items_to_be_drawn:
    screen.blit(item,(0,0))
```

and to change the order you can use something like this:
[How can I reorder a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177590/how-can-i-reorder-a-list-in-python)

items at the start of list will be at the back and every subsequent item will be on top of the last