# How to manipulate the *args input of a function?

Tags: python

I ran across this function that mostly does what I want, but I need to tweak it a bit.

The data I have looks like this:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
actual_x = torch.randn(13, 16, 64, 768)
```

But to work in the function below, I need to permute it to:

```
x = torch.randn(16, 64, 768, 13)
```

Inside the function, I cannot manipulate the value of `*args`. So if I wanted to add this line to reshape my data correctly inside the function: `args[0] = args[0].permute(1, 2, 3, 0)`

I get `'tuple' object does not support item assignment`.

```
class TimeDistributed(nn.Module):
    '''
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        super(TimeDistributed, self).__init__()
        self.n_layers = 13
        self.n_tokens = 64
        self.module = torch.nn.Linear(self.n_layers, self.n_tokens)

    def forward(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #only support tdim=1
        #args[0] = args[0].permute(1, 2, 3, 0)
        args = list(args[0])
        args = args.permute(1, 2, 3, 0)
        inp_shape = args[0].shape
        bs, seq_len = inp_shape[0], inp_shape[1]
        out = self.module(*[x.reshape(bs*seq_len, *x.shape[2:]) for x in args], **kwargs)
        out_shape = out.shape
        return out.view(bs, seq_len,*out_shape[1:])
```

It runs by:

```
TD1 = TimeDistributed()
out = TD1(x)
out.shape
```

It fails by:

```
TD1 = TimeDistributed()
out = TD1(actual_x)
out.shape
```

Comment: Nowhere in class `TimeDistributed` do I see any reference to `torch.randn` nor `args[0] = args[0].permute(1, 2, 3, 0)`. Why is this class being shown then?

Comment: I've edited it to show exactly where the problem is.

Comment: `*args` is a tuple, you will need to convert it to a list to support item assignment

Comment: There's nothing particularly special about `args`: it's a tuple, and tuples are immutable.

Comment: This makes even less sense. `TD1 = TimeDistributed()` is missing an argument and `out = TD1(x)` requires that class ` TimeDistributed` define method `__call__`. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert args to a list instead of a tuple with `args=list(args)`. Then you can reorder it how you please.

Comment: Would ‘listarg = *args’ give a list ?

Comment: No. The * used in that way is only valid when defining a function's inputs or when calling a function. When used as part of the argument list of a function, it signifies that any positional arguments (those provided without a keyword) will be collected into the input variable being denoted with the *. When calling a function, you can use it in front of a list or tuple to make it equivalent as if you passed each element of your list/tuple in as separate inputs to the function. You can't use the * in an assignment by itself, it's not a pointer dereference operator or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

I found googling:

```
a_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
order = [1, 0, 2]

a_list = [a_list[i] for i in order]

print(a_list)
OUTPUT
['b', 'a', 'c']
```

More here
[How can I reorder a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177590/how-can-i-reorder-a-list)