# How do I move my last element in the list to the 3rd position of the list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a list which should be stored under mylist.

```
#Here is my code.
mylist = [10,20,30,'apple',True,8.10]
mylist

output: [10, 20, 30, 'apple', True, 8.1]

#I want to add two numbers to the list using append()
mylist.append(30)
mylist.append(40)
```

But the out put has shown as below by getting added the elements two times.

```
mylist

output: [10, 20, 30, 'apple', True, 8.1,30,40,30,40]
```

Then I wanted to remove the extra numbers from the list 30,40

```
mylist.remove(40)
mylist.remove(30)
```

However I was able to remove both the elements contain 40 and one 30

```
mylist
output: [10, 20, 'apple', True, 8.1, 30]
```

#Now I want to move the last element to the 3rd position which should look like the below output.

```
mylist
desired output: [10,20,30,'apple',True, 8.1]
```

And finally I want to add my two extra elements 30,40 to 'mylist' using append() with out any repetitions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reorder a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177590/how-can-i-reorder-a-list)

Comment: Somehow you have a problem with your work environment.  The append() function DOES NOT add an element twice - that would not make any sense.  No one could use a language that worked that way.  I can't guess why you're seeing this but it's not the way Python works.

Comment: also as for adding an element to a specific index, try the `list.insert()` method

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `30` and `40` are appended to list only once. Save your code the `.py` file ad ru it.

Comment: Always strive to make example code that can be copied and reproduce the problem **without changes**.  As stated above, `.append` doesn't work that way.  Read the [mcve] guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

To move the last element to the 3rd position:

```
mylist.insert(2, mylist[-1])
mylist.pop(-1)
```

To add the elements:

```
mylist.append(30)
mylist.append(40)
```

Make sure you only call the append function once. Also check the list before calling append doesn't alredy have the 30 and 40.