# Shuffle position of elements in a list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shuffling a list of objects in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects-in-python)

IF I have a list:

> a = ["a", "b", "c", ..., "zzz"]

how can I randomly shuffle its elements in order to obtain a list:

> b = ["c", "zh", ...]

without consuming a lot of the system's resources?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects-in-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import random
b = list(a)
random.shuffle(b)
```

Comment: Python: just try the verb you are thinking™.

Answer (score 5):

[`random.shuffle()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle) shuffles a sequence in-place.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how much resources it consumes, but shuffle in the random module does exactly like this.

```
import random
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
random.shuffle(a)
```

Comment: It is returning a `None` value.

Comment: It affects the original list. print(a) do this after `random.shuffle(a)` this line.