# KeyError when trying to randomize a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, train-test-split

**Minimal Example:**
Consider this dataframe `temp`:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],"B":[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],"C":[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]})
>>> temp
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   2   3   4
2   3   4   5
3   4   5   6
4   5   6   7
5   6   7   8
6   7   8   9
7   8   9  10
8   9  10  11
9  10  11  12
```

Now, trying to shuffle each column at a time, in a for loop.

```
>>> for i in temp.columns:
...     np.random.shuffle(temp.loc[:,i])
...     print(temp)
...
    A   B   C
0   8   2   3
1   3   3   4
2   9   4   5
3   6   5   6
4   4   6   7
5  10   7   8
6   7   8   9
7   1   9  10
8   2  10  11
9   5  11  12
    A   B   C
0   8   7   3
1   3   9   4
2   9   8   5
3   6  10   6
4   4   4   7
5  10  11   8
6   7   5   9
7   1   3  10
8   2   2  11
9   5   6  12
    A   B   C
0   8   7   6
1   3   9   8
2   9   8   4
3   6  10  10
4   4   4   7
5  10  11  11
6   7   5   5
7   1   3   3
8   2   2  12
9   5   6   9
```

This works perfectly.
**Specific Example:**

Now, if I want to get a part of this dataframe, for training and testing purposes, then I'll use the `train_test_split` function from `sklearn.model_selection`.

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>>> temp = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],"B":[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],"C":[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]})
>>> y = [i for i in range(16,26)]
>>> len(y)
10
>>> X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(temp,y,test_size=0.2)
>>> X_train
    A   B   C
2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9
8   9  10  11
0   1   2   3
7   8   9  10
3   4   5   6
1   2   3   4
9  10  11  12
```

Now, we've obtained our `X_train` dataframe. In order to shuffle it's each column:

```
>>> for i in X_train.columns:
...     np.random.shuffle(X_train.loc[:,i])
...     print(X_train)
...
```

Which, unfortunately results in an error.
**Error:**

```
sys:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 4852, in mtrand.RandomState.shuffle
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 4855, in mtrand.RandomState.shuffle
  File "C:\Users\H.P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 623, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\H.P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2560, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 83, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 811, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 817, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 4
```

---

**Tracing for the problem and it's solution:**

Under the `SettingWithCopyWarning`, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments) question, which had this line under it's first answer:

> However it could create a copy which updates a copy of `data['amount']`
>   which you would not see. Then you would be wondering why it is not
>   updating.

**But, if this was the case, then why did the code work for the first case?**

It's also given in the answer that:

> Pandas returns a copy of an object in almost all method calls. The
>   inplace operations are a convience operation which work, but in
>   general are not clear that data is being modified and could
>   potentially work on copies.

So, instead of using `np.random.shuffle` we can use `np.random.permutation`, as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15474335/5345646) answer. So:

```
>>> for i in X_train.columns:
...     X_train.loc[:,i] = np.random.permutation(X_train.loc[:,i])
...     print(X_train)
...
```

But, I get the `SettingWithCopyWarning` again, and the answer too.

```
C:\Users\H.P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:621: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item_labels[indexer[info_axis]]] = value
    A   B   C
2  10   4   5
6   9   8   9
8   2  10  11
0   8   2   3
7   1   9  10
3   3   5   6
1   4   3   4
9   7  11  12
    A   B   C
2  10   5   5
6   9  11   9
8   2   4  11
0   8   9   3
7   1   3  10
3   3   8   6
1   4  10   4
9   7   2  12
    A   B   C
2  10   5  10
6   9  11   5
8   2   4  11
0   8   9   3
7   1   3   4
3   3   8   6
1   4  10  12
9   7   2   9
```

This can be a workaround.

---

### Questions:

1. Why does the code work for the first case, and not the second case, when I use `train_test_split`?
2. Why do I still get the `SettingWithCopyWarning` when I'm not using the inplace shuffler `np.random.shuffle`?

### Requests for Suggestions:

1. Is there a better (easy to use/error free/faster) method to do column shuffling?

Comment: This does not look like a _minimal_ example.

Comment: Any reason you can't create a DataFrame as required with randomised values instead of mutating an existing one?

Comment: @DyZ Why? `train_test_split` of a smaller dataset wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @JonClements Good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.Why does the code work for the first case, and not the second case, when I use `train_test_split`?

Because train_test_split shuffles the rows of `X_train`. and hence the index of each column is not a range but a set of values

you can see this by inspecting the index of `temp` and `X_train`

```
X_train.index
Int64Index([6, 8, 9, 5, 0, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')

temp.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1)
```

In the first case, the column can safely be treated as a an array unlike in the second case. if you change the code in the second case to

```
for i in X_train.columns:
    np.random.shuffle(X_train.loc[:,i].values)
    print(X_train)
```

this will not cause an error.

**Note that the shuffling in the case you presented will result in a different shuffle for each column. i.e. the data points will get mixed up.**

> 2.Why do I still get the `SettingWithCopyWarning` when I'm not using the inplace shuffler `np.random.shuffle`?

I don't get the warning when using the latest version of pandas (0.22.0)

> **Requests for Suggestions:**
>
> 1. Is there a better (easy to use/error free/faster) method to do column shuffling?

I suggest using sample when `axis=1`, it will shuffle the columns, and the number of samples should be the number of columns. i.e `X_train.shape[1]`

```
X_train = X_train.sample(X_train.shape[1],axis=1)

In []: X_train.sample(X_train.shape[1],axis=1)
Out[]: 
    B   A   C
6   8   7   9
9  11  10  12
8  10   9  11
4   6   5   7
5   7   6   8
0   2   1   3
2   4   3   5
3   5   4   6
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer! But I think you mistook my request for suggestion. I didn't want to shuffle columns themselves. Instead, I wanted to shuffle the values of a column, with the other columns' values remaining the same for each row.

Comment: I see. then you can still use sample i.e. `X_train = X_train.apply(lambda col: col.sample(len(col)))` . but like I said this will get the data points mixed up

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem with train_test_split.  I used this instead:

```
np.random.shuffle(x.iloc[:, i].values)
```

Not sure why it works, but it seems to fix the problem