# Fisher-Yates shuffling

Tags: python, shuffle, fisher-yates-shuffle

I am writing to ask what is the difference between using a Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm to shuffle a dataset compared to using `np.random.permutation` just like in the following code snippet:

```
X.shape[1] # number of training examples

permutation = list(np.random.permutation(m))
shuffled_X = X[:, permutation]
shuffled_Y = Y[:, permutation].reshape((1,m))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shuffle vs permute numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474159/shuffle-vs-permute-numpy)

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not quite sure of the difference. Could you please explain?

Comment: Sure.  [The source for `permutation`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L4922) shows that numpy just sets up a range and then calls `shuffle`, so the underlying algorithm is Fisher-Yates.  The difference between permutation and shuffle is that you can call the former with either an array or an integer, and that the latter does its work in-place.