# Defining Classes in Python

Tags: python

Create a class `Deck` that represents a deck of cards. Your class should have the following methods:

- constructor: creates a new deck of 52 cards in standard order.
- shuffle: randomnizes the order of the cards.
- dealCard: returns a single card from the top of the deck and removes the card from the deck
- cardsLeft: returns the number of cards remaining in the deck.

Test your program by having it deal out a sequence of `n` cards from a shuffle deck where `n` is the user input.

```
class Deck:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cardList=[]
        for suit in ["d","c","h","s"]:
            for rank in range(1,14):
                card=PlayingCard(suit, rank)
                self.cardList.append(card)
    def shuffle(self):
    #I DON'T KNOW HOW TO SHUFFLE MY CARDS PLEASE HELP.
    #self.cardList[pos1] = self.cardList[pos2]
    #self.cardList[pos2] = self.cardList[pos1]
    #these two lines above are not working
    def dealCard(self):
        return self.cardList.pop() 

    def cardsLeft(self):
        return len(self.cardList)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @BrenBarn According to the comments buried in the code they want to know how to shuffle the deck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs on `random.shuffle`. It should help you greatly! :)

```
from collections import namedtuple
from random import shuffle

PlayingCard = namedtuple('PlayingCard', "suit rank")

class Deck:

    def __init__(self):
    self.cardList = [PlayingCard(suit, rank) for suit in"dchs" for rank in range(1,14)]

    def shuffle(self):
        shuffle(self.cardList)

    def dealCard(self):
        return self.cardList.pop() 

    def cardsLeft(self):
        return len(self.cardList)

d = Deck()
d.shuffle()
print [d.dealCard() for _ in range(5)]
```