# Random without repetition?

Tags: python, random

I want to write a program that displays all the elements of a list in random order without repetition. 
It seems to me that it should work, but only prints those elements with repetition.

```
import random

tab = []

for i in range(1, 8):
    item = random.choice(["house", "word", "computer", "table", "cat", "enter", "space"])
    if item not in tab:
        print(item)
    else:
        tab.append(item)
        continue
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shuffling a list of objects in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects-in-python)

Answer (score 14):

Instead of `random.choice` within the `for` loop, use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) here.

This way, your list is guaranteed to be have all the elements, while also maintaining the requirement of random order:

```
>>> import random
>>> tab = ["house", "word", "computer", "table", "cat", "enter", "space"]
>>> random.shuffle(tab)
>>> print tab
```

---

As for your original code, that will not work, since the `if else` block as you've written ensures that no element is added within the list `tab`. You could correct that by removing the else block like below:

```
>>> for i in range(1, 8):
...     item = random.choice(["house", "word", "computer", "table", "cat", "enter", "space"])
...     if item not in tab:
...         print(item)
...         tab.append(item)
... 
house
cat
space
enter
```

But now you will need to alter the logic so that the runs in which same value is randomly returned don't affect the number of outputs.

Answer (score 7):

Read about capabilities of Random library.
It can write simpler. For example:

```
import random

data = ["house", "word", "computer", "table", "cat", "enter", "space"]
x = random.sample(data, len(data))
print(x)
```

Comment: a perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
items = ["house", "word", "computer", "table", "cat", "enter", "space"]
tab= []
while len(tab) < len(items):
    item = random.choice(items)
    if item not in tab:
    tab.append(item)
print(tab)
```

Comment: Ple add some description to this answer

Answer (score 0):

As Anshul pointed out the use of random shuffle is great:

```
import random

options = ["house", "word", "computer", "table", "cat", "enter", "space"]
random.shuffle(options)
print (options)
```

If you however do not want to import the random library it is possible to solve the problem like below:

```
options_shuffled = []
options = ["house", "word", "computer", "table", "cat", "enter", "space"]
while len(options) > 0:
    random_bytes = open('/dev/urandom', 'rb').read(4)
    idx = int(int.from_bytes(random_bytes, 'big') / 2 ** (8 * 4) * len(options))
    options_shuffled.append(options[idx])
    del options[idx]

print (options_shuffled)
```