# Virtual bot random.choices and os.startfile()

Tags: python, random, bots

I was making this virtual bot on Python using many modules out of which some were (os and random) so in this virtual bot it asks me what I want to do I respond to it and gives me outcomes based on what I asked or told it to do.

So, I was trying to add another feature in this code, where, I ask it to play a game it asks me which game and I respond and it opens the game I tell it to.

```
elif "jarvis play a game" in query or "jarvis play one of my games" in query or "jarvis play my games" in query:
    speak("ok", "I have 6 games", "they are", "breakout arcade game", "car arcade game", "obstrucal course game", "football champs", "path finder", "and", "tic tac toe", "which of these games would you like to play?")
    wgp = takeCommand().lower()
    if wgp == "breakout arcade game":
        speak("ok, opening breakout arcade game, have fun")
        os.startfile("breakout arcade gaming.py")

    elif wgp == "car arcade game":
        speak("ok, opening car arcade game, have fun")
        os.startfile("car arcade gaming.py")

    elif wgp == "obstrucal course game":
        speak("ok, opening obstrucal course game, have fun")
        os.startfile("complete obby game! - ursina.py")

    elif wgp == "football champs":
        speak("ok, opening football champs, have fun")
        os.startfile("football champs.py")

    elif wgp == "path finder":
        speak("ok, opening path finder, have fun")
        os.startfile("path finder.py")

    elif wgp == "tic tac toe":
        speak("ok, opening tic tac toe, have fun")
        os.startfile("tic tac toe2options.py")

    elif wgp == "choose a random game":
        speak("ok")
        game = ["tic tac toe2options.py","football champs.py","complete obby game! - ursina.py"]
        choose = random.choices(game)
        os.startfile(choose)
```

This is only a part of the code so the `elif` statement is not an error, query is the thing that hears and saves what we say. So in this code everything works but the last `elif` statement where I try making it choose a random game between the given file names that they are saved as, it should choose one of those and I want the `os.startfile()` to start a file that was randomly chosen between the given ones in the list. However when I run this code it gives me an error saying:

```
line 24, in <module>
    os.startfile(choose)
TypeError: startfile: filepath should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list
[Finished in 0.6s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Vatsa\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\all main py files\pyautogui basics 2.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\Vatsa\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\all main py files]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Android;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\bin;C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Vatsa\.dotnet\tools]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) returns "a *k* sized list of elements…", so you would need to use:

```
choose = random.choices(game)
os.startfile[choose[0])
```

For obvious reasons, it would probably be better to use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) here…

```
choice = random.choice(game)
os.startfile(choice)
```

Comment: ohh great! it works now thank you so much also i had a question if we could like decrease the chance of the same thing to repeat is there any way we cud do that?

Comment: [Random without repetition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735892/random-without-repetition)