# How can I generate a new, random value in a list in Python 3 repeatedly until all values have been randomly picked (once)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from easygui import *
from time import *
from statedict import *
import random

correctnum = 0
questionsanswered = 0
print("Indian Map Quiz v1")
sleep(0.5)
print("Note all features might not work correctly, this is a work in progress.")


msgbox("Welcome to Indian Map Quiz", "INDIA", "Continue")

title = "Guess The State"
msg = "What Indian state is this?"

stateFactList = [APdict, ARdict, ASdict, BRdict, CTdict, GAdict, GJdict, HPdict, HRdict, JHdict,
                 KAdict, KLdict, MHdict, MLdict, MNdict, MPdict, MZdict, NLdict, ODdict, PBdict,
                 RJdict, SKdict, TGdict, TNdict, TRdict, UPdict, UTdict, WBdict]




stateID = random.choice(stateFactList)
print(stateID["state"])
stateQuestion = buttonbox(msg=msg, title=title, choices=stateID["choices"], image=stateID["image file"])

if stateQuestion == stateID["correct"]:
    print("it's correct")
    correctnum += 1
    questionsanswered += 1
else:
    print("incorrect")
    questionsanswered += 1
```

Here is the code, essentially when you run the program, it should randomly pick a state and provide some multiple choice answers based on the state. It randomly picks a state from the stateFactlist list and matches it with a dictionary stored in another file. Whenever the user answers a question, I want it to generate a new, random state to be displayed to the user, along with the respective multiple choice answers, but I can't find a way to implement it. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random without repetition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735892/random-without-repetition)

Comment: hint: in some variable you can track already picked from the list, or better remove picked element from the list

Comment: @adrianop01 random.sample() will give unique elemnts from the list but when you call again on list it might give repetations

Comment: @Hackaholic what do you mean by "might give repetitions"? There is a limited number of possible permutations for any finite list, running ANY sampling algorithms to generate a permutation of a finite list will eventually encounter repetitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help clear up the confusion, `random.sample()` includes a parameter, `k`, which lets you specify the number of `unique elements` to randomly choose from the specified sequence.  It can work well for what OP has in mind.  Here is a simplified example for illustration purposes:

```
import random

arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
for x in random.sample(arr, k=len(arr)):
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
C
D
A
B
```

---

EDIT: In response to OP's question on how to implement this in their code, here is a rough approximation.  The key is to move the state Q&A code inside of a loop that is iterating (in random order) over `stateFactList`.  Note, I wasn't able to run this code since I don't have access to OP's data structures or GUI library, so take it as a **rough** guide, not working code.

```
stateFactList = [APdict, ARdict, ASdict, BRdict, CTdict, GAdict, GJdict, HPdict, HRdict, JHdict,
                 KAdict, KLdict, MHdict, MLdict, MNdict, MPdict, MZdict, NLdict, ODdict, PBdict,
                 RJdict, SKdict, TGdict, TNdict, TRdict, UPdict, UTdict, WBdict]

for stateID in random.sample(stateFactList, k=len(stateFactList)):  # iterate over stateFactList in random order 

    msg = "What Indian state is this?"

    # This statement no longer needed
    # stateID = random.choice(stateFactList)
    
    print(stateID["state"])
    stateQuestion = buttonbox(msg=msg, title=title, choices=stateID["choices"], image=stateID["image file"])

    if stateQuestion == stateID["correct"]:
        print("it's correct")
        correctnum += 1
        questionsanswered += 1
    else:
        print("incorrect")
        questionsanswered += 1
```

Comment: how could i implement this in my code? This isn't very compatible with my program as it isn't compatible with my if statements, and with my buttonbox.

Comment: Good question @Mohammed, hopefully my edit above points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Just shuffle the list, then iterate normally.

```
randome.shuffle(stateFactList)
for state in stateFactList:
    ...
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the `sample`-approach is just a hidden way of shuffling

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the already picked element from the list for fair share

Like below example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> choice = random.choice(a)
>>> choice
4
>>> a.remove(a.index(choice))     # removes 4 from the list
>>> a
[1, 2, 4, 5]
>>> choice = random.choice(a)
>>> choice
2
```