# How do you enter numbers into a list without any being repeated?

Tags: python, list, random

I am trying to make a list with the numbers 1-24 all in it in a random order, why doesn't this work?

```
full_list = []

x = 0
while x < 25 :
    n = randint (1,24) 
    while n in full_list:
        n = randint (1,24)
    full_list.append(n)
    x = x + 1
```

Comment: check if the new number is already in the list. Discard if it is, and pick again

Comment: or simpler use shuffle -- see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects-in-python

Comment: You want something like `shuffle(range(1,25))`

Comment: The code doesn't work because your loop doesn't stop until 25 numbers have been added, out of a possible unique set of 24 numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

random has a `shuffle` function that would make more sense for this task:

```
ar = list(range(1,25))
random.shuffle(ar)
ar
> [20, 14, 2, 11, 15, 10, 3, 4, 16, 23, 13, 19, 5, 21, 8, 7, 17, 9, 6, 12, 22, 18, 1, 24]
```

Also, your solution doesn't work because `while x < 25` needs to be `while x < 24`.  It is in an infinite loop when `x = 24` (since `randint(1,24)` will never generate a new number not in the list).