# Is it possible to create a new list from a shuffled list?

Tags: python, list, random, shuffle

```
OriginalName = ["a", "b", "c"]

ShuffleList = random.shuffle(OriginalName)
print ShuffleList
```

When I run the above, it returns as 'None'. I am trying to create a new list once it has been shuffled.

I want to create another list that has been created randomly and may resemble `["c", "a", "b"]`

Comment: Thre's a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects-in-python `random.shuffle` does this in place so returns None and changes the original data - either copy it or use ` random.sample(OriginalName, len(OriginalName))` instead

Answer (score 9):

`random.shuffle` is re-organizing the original list - you are only working with one list.

Try something like

```
OriginalName = ["a", "b", "c"]
ShuffleList = list(OriginalName)  # making a new list copy

random.shuffle(ShuffleList)
```

Now you have two lists, the original and shuffled.

Side note: make sure to use snake case (`original_name` instead of `OriginalName`). It's Python convention.

Comment: I want another list, that has been created randomly, and will resemble something like `["c", "a", "b"]`. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, `ShuffeList` is a copy of your original list, which is then shuffled in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Create the new list first, then shuffle that.

```
shuffled = OriginalName[:]
random.shuffle(shuffled)
print shuffled
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) for this

```
import random
l = list(range(5))
print(random.sample(l, len(l)))
```

prints something like

```
[4, 0, 2, 1, 3]
```