# builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute shuffle

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to define a function that returns a shuffled list l1 without changing the original list l using the method random.shuffle but I got this error message:

`builtin_function_or_method object has no attribute shuffle`

```
import random
def shuffle_list(l):
  l1=random.shuffle(l)
  return(l1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from random import shuffle
def shuffle_list(l):
  def shuffle_list(l):
    shuffle(l)
    return l
```

Import shuffle directly and return `l` and don't save it into any variable because `l1 = shuffle(l)` will return `None`

I know this is coming late.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all instances of `random.shuffle()` with `shuffle()` after changing the `import random` with `from random import shuffle`.

Answer (score 0):

random.shuffle changes the order of the list in place and returns None.

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3]
>>> shuffle_list(lst)
>>> print lst
[3, 1, 2]
>>> shuffle_list(lst)
>>> print lst
[1, 3, 2]
```

So if you don't care about the order of the original list, your code could simply be:

```
import random
random.shuffle(l)
```

Comment: but the original list changes when I use the simple method, i wanna a shuffled copy, without modifying the original list

Comment: In that case, someone answered that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12978830/6616057

Answer (score 0):

`random.shuffle()` modifies the list in-place and doesn't return anything, so you need to first make a copy of the list argument, shuffle, and then return it, in order to preserve the original:

```
import random

def shuffle_list(lst):
    lst2 = lst.copy()
    random.shuffle(lst2)
    return lst2

items = list(range(10))
shuffled = shuffle_list(items)

print(items)    # => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(shuffled) # => [6, 2, 1, 9, 3, 0, 8, 4, 5, 7] (or some other rearrangement)
```

Comment: Can anyone please explain the error message, even if i apply the method on a copy nothing changes