# replace some parts for cloze deletion test

Tags: javascript, python

For example, I have this text: `This is a good reason to stop.` (word counts is always greater than 5)

```
words = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'reason', 'to', 'stop']
flashcards_count = ciel(len(word) / 3)
```

The result I'd like to have:

```
[
'This __ a good ______ to ____.'
'____ is a ____ reason __ stop.'
'This is _ good reason to stop.'
]
```

As you may notice I'm try to avoid putting blanks in sequence, except if it's the last flashcard.

So for this, I shuffled the `words` and chunked it into 3 to make each flashcard, but the result might be like this:

```
[
'This is a ____ ______ __ stop.'
'____ __ _ good reason to stop.'
'This is a good reason to ____.'
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - do you mean that you want to shuffle a list, trying to ensure that every word has at least one 'new' word in between it and it's previous neighbours?

Comment: yes, exactly, it was really hard for me to explain that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the random module to shuffle a list of strings, then join them with a space inbewteen :

```
import random
list = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'reason', 'to', 'make', 'stop']
random.shuffle(list)
print " ".join(list)
```

Take a look at [Shuffling a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects) if you want to shuffle non-strings aswel.

Comment: I've changed the question, I know how to shuffle a list in python!