# Unbiased Random List Generation

Tags: python-3.x, random, shuffle, sampling

### Problem Statement

I need to simulate the process of [100 Prisoner Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_prisoners_problem), in which each drawer of a cupboard of size 100 contains a unique number from 0 to 99. I initialze the number of drawers as follows:

```
def arrange_event(n_prisoners=100):
    if (n_prisoners % 2) != 0 or n_prisoners <=0:
        raise ValueError("Number of prisoners must be a postive and even number.")
    drawer = list(range(n_prisoners))
    random.shuffle(drawer)
    return drawer
```

But I doubt that this implementation (e.g.shuffling from a specific list) will introduce bias to some specific patterns during sampling. A correct implemenation of list initialzation is needed. Any explanation of the bias (if exists) introduced in this implementation will be helpful as well.

## Note

I'm not simply asking how to make each initiazation random, the key is that **the probabilty of each permutation should be equal** in the expcted implemetation, which is completely different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects).

Here's what I found in the [official document](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html), which suggests that the probability distrbution over permutations are biased in my implemetation using `random.shuffle()`.

> random.shuffle(x[, random])
>
> Shuffle the sequence x in place. The optional argument random is a 0-argument function returning a random float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, this is the function random().
>
> Note that for even rather small len(x), the total number of permutations of x is larger than the period of most random number generators; this implies that most permutations of a long sequence can never be generated.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects
I don't think python random would be secure for cryptographic applications, but will probably work fine for this. Do you have a specific problem with the output it is giving?

Comment: My problem is not only making each initialization random, the key is to make the distribution over each permutation a uniform one.

Comment: Then I guess use the system random number generator, which is constantly seeded with more data and thus doesn't really have a "period". See [`random.SystemRandom()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom).

Comment: This function may be useful, but I don't see how this will make shuffling from a fixed sequence produce uniform distribution over permutations of this sequence. Maybe shuffling is not the correct approach, but I didn't know what is.

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand the problem, because `SystemRandom` should generate a uniform distribution, or at least the closest you'll get without using some sort of hardware RNG.

Comment: @BorisPolonsky, what do you mean by uniform distribution? Do you want the shuffle to be the same each time? If you mean it in the strict mathematics sense, Rython random does this.

Comment: @MikeS159 By saying uniform distribution I mean each permutation of the sequence (not a single number) should be of identical probability of being generated. I've already figured out a naive approach for doing this.

Comment: @glibdud I figured out a solution for making probability of each permutation identical by sampling without replacement(see the proposal of my answer). I used `random.choice` instead but still I don't know if this solution is equivalent to using `SystemRandom`.

Answer (score 0):

I use a naive approach to make probability of each permutation equal, by  sampling without replacement while keeping the order of number sampled. The implementation is as follows:

```
def arrange_event(n_prisoners=100):
    if (n_prisoners % 2) != 0 or n_prisoners <=0:
        raise ValueError("Number of prisoners must be a postive and even number.")
    drawer = list(range(n_prisoners))
    for i in range(n_prisoners, 1, -1):
        random_index = random.choice(range(i))
        swap_a, swap_b = drawer[random_index], drawer[i-1]
        drawer[random_index], drawer[i-1] = swap_b, swap_a
    return drawer
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you think this is more uniform than using `random.shuffle()`?

Comment: In fact, looking closer, this is functionally identical to how Python's [`random.shuffle()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9285835a05ad0319acef111340266c0f85ed549c/Lib/random.py#L286) works. I'm not sure what advantage you think re-implementing it in your code conveys.

Comment: @glibdud So I suppose you suggestion is that I should specify parameter `random` in `random.shuffle()` with the corresponding method in class `random.SystemRandom` to address the "period" issue, correct?

Comment: Or use SystemRandom directly: `random.SystemRandom().shuffle(drawer)`. Of course, this only matters if you plan on processing at least `(2**19937-1)/(n-1)` iterations of the problem, as that's how long it would take to get to a repeated state of the standard PRNG.

Comment: @glibdid Your solution is truely helpful for me. As for your curiosity, I posted this question because I remembered reading some post saying that some company use shuffle for such purpose (not written in Python), and the simulation results tuned out to be biased. I can't find that post again, that's why I end up posting this question here to ensure that my implementation in Python is unbiased.