# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index with 1D numpy indices array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to write a function that randomly picks elements from a training set, based on the **bin probabilities** provided. I **divide the set indices to 11 bins**, then create **custom probabilities** for them.

```
bin_probs = [0.5, 0.3, 0.15, 0.04, 0.0025, 0.0025, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001]

X_train = list(range(2000000))

train_probs = bin_probs * int(len(X_train) / len(bin_probs)) # extend probabilities across bin elements
train_probs.extend([0.001]*(len(X_train) - len(train_probs))) # a small fix to match number of elements
train_probs = train_probs/np.sum(train_probs) # normalize
indices = np.random.choice(range(len(X_train)), replace=False, size=50000, p=train_probs)
out_images = X_train[indices.astype(int)] # this is where I get the error
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index with 1D numpy indices array
```

I find this weird, since I already checked the array of indices that I have created. It is **1-D**, it is **integer**, and it is **scalar**.

What am I missing?

Note : I tried to pass `indices` with `astype(int)`. Same error.

Comment: For those who encounter this error recently in sklearn's `hdbscan` and reach this question, re-install your sklearn (version 1.4.1post1) with `pip` if it was installed with `conda`—for reasons I don't know.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

Perhaps the error message is somewhat misleading, but the gist is that `X_train` is a list, not a numpy array. You cannot use array indexing on it. Make it an array first:

```
out_images = np.array(X_train)[indices.astype(int)]
```

Comment: I see. But, what if the list is too big to be converted to an array? The original X_train is a list of images in fact.

Comment: Then try [shuffling the original list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects).

Comment: This saved me a lot of time troubleshooting! (It's a very misleading error message)

Comment: An alternative is to use list comprehension if one insists that `X_train` and `out_images` have to remain a list. `out_images = [X_train[index] for index in indices]`

Comment: What if I really do have a lists of lists, i.e. I cannot convert to an array (each list is of a different length)

Comment: @seeker_after_truth use list comprehension as mentioned in Nuclear03020704 's answer.

Answer (score 189):

I get this error whenever I use `np.concatenate` the wrong way:

```
>>> a = np.eye(2)
>>> np.concatenate(a, a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in concatenate
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

The correct way is to input the two arrays as a tuple:

```
>>> np.concatenate((a, a))
array([[1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.]])
```

Comment: I fell into the same trap. It's very easy to overlook `np.concatenate()` 's requirement that the arrays to be concatenated must be supplied as a tuple. Many thanks!

Comment: same with `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix( (values, (rows,columns)) )`

Answer (score 12):

A simple case that generates this error message:

```
In [8]: [1,2,3,4,5][np.array([1])]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-55def8e1923d> in <module>()
----> 1 [1,2,3,4,5][np.array([1])]

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Some variations that work:

```
In [9]: [1,2,3,4,5][np.array(1)]     # this is a 0d array index
Out[9]: 2
In [10]: [1,2,3,4,5][np.array([1]).item()]    
Out[10]: 2
In [11]: np.array([1,2,3,4,5])[np.array([1])]
Out[11]: array([2])
```

Basic python list indexing is more restrictive than numpy's:

```
In [12]: [1,2,3,4,5][[1]]
....
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

### edit

Looking again at

```
indices = np.random.choice(range(len(X_train)), replace=False, size=50000, p=train_probs)
```

`indices` is a 1d array of integers - but it certainly isn't scalar.  It's an array of 50000 integers.  List's cannot be indexed with multiple indices at once, regardless of whether they are in a list or array.

Answer (score 1):

Another case that could cause this error is

```
>>> np.ndindex(np.random.rand(60,60))
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Using the actual shape will fix it.

```
>>> np.ndindex(np.random.rand(60,60).shape)
<numpy.ndindex object at 0x000001B887A98880>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're passing the right arguments. Similar to [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62956993/5049813), I was passing two arrays to `np.all` when it only accepted one array, meaning that the second array was interpreted to be an axis.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use x_train.shape[] instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).