# KMeans implementation in python with OOP?

Tags: python, algorithm, k-means, implementation

I am trying to implement KMeans algorithm as a class and when i done all code i test with creating object and than train the dataset. But i get the following error. 
self.distances = np.zeros((self.N, self.n_clusters))

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class KMeansInterface(ABC):

    @abstractmethod 
    def fit(self, X):
        pass

    @abstractmethod     
    def predict(self, X):
        pass

class Kmeans(KMeansInterface):
    def __init__(self, n_clusters):
        self.n_clusters = n_clusters
        self.labels = None
        self.distances = None
        self.N = X.shape[0]
        self.data_points = X
        self.prev_labels = None

    def choose_clusters(self, k, X):
        self.n_clusters = k
        size = X.shape[0]
        numbers = np.random.choice(size, k, replace=False)
        return X[numbers]

    def calculate_sum_squared_distance(self, data_points, clusters):
        self.distances = np.zeros((self.N, self.n_clusters))
        for i, centroid in enumerate(clusters):
            distance = np.sum(np.square(data_points-centroid), axis=1)
            self.distances[:, i] = distance
        return self.distances

    def calculate_closest_clusters(self, distances):
        self.closest_clusters = np.argmin(self.distances, axis=1)
        return self.closest_clusters

    def update_clusters(self, labels, data_points):
        new_clusters = []
        for i in range(self.n_clusters):
            points_in_cluster = data_points[labels==i]
            values = np.mean(points_in_cluster, axis=0)
            new_clusters.append(values)
        return np.array(new_clusters)



    def fit(self, X):
        self.n_clusters = self.choose_clusters(self.n_clusters, X)

        for i in range(20000):
            self.distances = self.calculate_sum_squared_distance(X, self.n_clusters)
            self.labels = self.calculate_closest_clusters(self.distances)
            self.new_cluster = self.update_clusters(self.labels, X)
            if self.prev_labels is not None:         
                if np.all(self.prev_labels == self.labels):
                    break
            self.prev_labels = self.labels
            fitted = True
        return self.labels

    def predict(self, X, clusters):
        self.distances = self.calculate_sum_squared_distance(X, clusters)
        self.labels = self.calculate_closest_clusters(self.distances)
        return self.labels

kmean_object = KMeans(2)
kmean_object.fit(X)
```

Comment: its answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997928/typeerror-only-integer-scalar-arrays-can-be-converted-to-a-scalar-index-with-1d

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index with 1D numpy indices array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997928/typeerror-only-integer-scalar-arrays-can-be-converted-to-a-scalar-index-with-1d)