# Error when trying to set column as index in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

I have the following code:

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=[['att1', 'att2']])
A['idx'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
A
```

which works fine until I do (trying to set column 'idx' as in index for the dataframe)

```
A.set_index('idx', inplace=True)
```

which throws an error

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

What does this mean ?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997928/typeerror-only-integer-scalar-arrays-can-be-converted-to-a-scalar-index-with-1d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is when you create `A` with

```
columns = [['att1', 'att2']]
```

If you print `A.columns` you will get:

```
MultiIndex([('att1',),
            ('att2',),
            ( 'idx',)],
           )
```

So `'idx'` is not really in your column for you to set index. Now, this would work:

```
A.set_index(('idx',))
```

and give:

```
       att1 att2
(idx,)          
a         1    2
b         1    3
c         4    6
```

However, you should fix your creation of `A` with just:

```
columns = ['att1', 'att2']
```