# Indexing list of cuda tensors gives error - "can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy"

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am having a list of cuda tensors:

```
>>> X_train
[tensor([  101,  3533...='cuda:0'), tensor([  101,  3422...='cuda:0'), tensor([  101,  2054...='cuda:0'), tensor([ 101, 1019, ...='cuda:0'), tensor([  101, 14674...='cuda:0'), tensor([  101,  9246...='cuda:0'), tensor([  101,  2054...='cuda:0'), tensor([  101,  2339...='cuda:0), ... ]
```

I am trying to apply k-fold cross validation. So I want to index this list using list of k-fold indices:

```
>>> X_train[train_index]
```

But it gives me error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50997969/1317018) answer, the issue is that I cannot index list using list of indices. It is allowed in numpy.

So I tried to convert it to numpy:

```
np.array(X_train)
```

But it gave me error:

```
TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
```

Do I really have to move these individual cuda tensors to cpu before indexing?
How can I easily index this list of cuda tensors while keeping them on cuda (to utilize GPU for training model)? Or its not possible and I should first index them (by first forming them as numpy array) and then move the indexed ones to cuda? Is there any stadard / preferrable practice followed to handle the data?

Comment: Have you tried converting the list to a tensor using `torch.stack(X_train, dim=0)`?

Answer (score 0):

Converting to [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) just for indexing is really a bad option:
This incurs copy operations between GPU and CPU and in general can [disrupt PyTorch's computational graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63582590/why-do-we-call-detach-before-calling-numpy-on-a-pytorch-tensor/63869655#63869655).

What you can do instead is use [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension):

```py
subset = [X_train[i_] for i_ in train_index]
```