# How do I fix a TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index?

Tags: python, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I need to write a Python code **without any loops** which for a given regular upper triangular matrix R ∈ Rn×n (that is rij = 0 for j > i and rii ̸= 0) and given c ∈ Rn solves the linear system Rx = c using backward substitution and returns the vector x.
The backward substitution is defined as:
[backward substitution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBKeO.png)
This is what I have so far:

```
def backward(R, c):
    n = len(c)
    x = np.zeros(n)

    x[-1] = c[-1] / R[-1, -1]

    i = np.arange(n-2, -1, -1)
    j = i+1

    x[i] = (c[i] - R[i, j::-1] @ x[j::-1]) / R[i, i]

    return x
```

If I try to test this code, it returns following error message:
---> 10     x[i] = (c[i] - R[i, j::-1] @ x[j::-1]) / R[i, i]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

What I am trying to do is to first compute the last entry of the vector x and from then on compute the other elements using the backward substitution formula. But I have trouble accessing the j-indices since in order for this code to properly work, I have to use more than one element in a row. E.g. if I have a 3x3 matrix A, I have to use A11, A12 and A13 to compute x1.

How do I fix that issue?

Comment: You said **"(that is rij = 0 for j > i and rii ̸= 0)"**, the keyword being **for**, following by a condition – this indicates that you will require loops. There may be a mathematical way to derive what you need, but generally, you can't solve these kinds of problems without using loops in some form.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know this should be a comment but I don't have enough rep so [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50997969/10157264) a good answer from DYZ.