# Is there a way to mix/'shuffle' values in a list in python?

Tags: python, list, shuffle

I am trying to create a Deck of cards type scenario, which I want to 'shuffle' and then pick a 'card'. The cards are in a list as 'S6' (6 of spades), 'CJ' (Jack of Clubs) and I want a card to be picked from index value 0 (top of the deck), and so would like to be able to move around each value in the list randomly.

Side question- Would picking a card by using a randomly generated index number produce a similar result? Coding Newboy here!

Comment: [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

Comment: Try using a tuple to store a suit and value to represent a card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use `random.shuffle()` to mix up a list.

If you had a deck with the cards in order you could do something like

`random.shuffle(deck)`

Answer (score 0):

As @dawg says, use random.shuffle:

```
import random
items = ['jack', 'king', 'queen', 'ace']
random.shuffle(items)
```

The function applies the change `in-place`, which means it alters the original object passed in and returns `None`.

> See here
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/976921/9917694