# Shuffle an item to a list python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a List in python. I want to add a new item to this list. But I want to shuffle (insert to a random place in list with saving the order of other elements ) it to The list exactly. 
I want Something like this:

```
A = [2,4,3,6,7,3,3,4,6]
B = 5
shuffle(A,B)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It's really not clear what you want this shuffle function to do. It sounds like you want to use the `insert` list method?

Comment: What would be the expected result of "shuffling it to the list exactly"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shuffling a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add new element to list and shuffle list

```
A = [2,4,3,6,7,3,3,4,6]
B = 5
A.append(B)
shuffle(A)
```

or... if you want to insert `B` to random position:

```
from random import randint

A.insert(randint(0, len(A)), B)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use random to shuffle a list:

```
import random

A = [2,4,3,6,7,3,3,4,6]
B = 5

A.append(B)  # adds B to A
random.shuffle(A)  # shuffle the list
print(A)
```

returns:

```
[4, 3, 4, 6, 7, 3, 6, 5, 3, 2]
```