# Built-in way to do immutable shuffle in Python (CPython)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

The `random.shuffle()` built-in shuffles in place, which is fine for many purposes. But suppose we would want to leave the original collection intact, and generate a random permutation based on the original sequence, is there a prefered way to do this in the standard library?

When I look at [CPython's random.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py) I see an intial comment that reads:

```
sequences
    ---------
           pick random element
           pick random sample
           pick weighted random sample
           generate random permutation
```

Particularly, the last line is of interest. However, I struggle to see what method in this class achieves this.

Naturally, this is not a hard problem to solve, even for a novice Python programmer. But it would be nice to have a standard way of doing it in the standard library, and I'm sure it must exist somewhere. Perhaps someplace other than `random.py`?

Comment: Is in the docs `sample(x, k=len(x))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs of [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle), you could use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

> To shuffle an immutable sequence and return a new shuffled list, use `sample(x, k=len(x))` instead of `shuffle()`.

The same thing was analized in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12978830/9225671)

Comment: Thanks. It seems to me this operation is common enough that it'd warrant its own name. But using `sample()` in this manner obviously does work.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like the obvious solution that shouldn't do more work than necessary:

```
def shuffled(gen):
    ls = list(gen)
    random.shuffle(ls)
    return ls
```

Since it's so simple to build from stdlib primitives, I'm not sure it would make sense to include this as a separate primitive.