# How do I get a python quiz to randomize questions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

My task is to make a quiz using python, with questions being stored in an external file. However, I can not figure out how to get my questions to randomize and only display 10 at a time out of the 20 possible

I have tried using import random however the syntax `random.shuffle(question)` does not seem to be valid. I am not sure what to do now.

The *question.txt* file is laid out as:

```
Category
Question
Answer
Answer
Answer
Answer
Correct Answer
Explanation
```

My code:

```
#allows program to know how file should be read
def open_file(file_name, mode):
    """Open a file."""
    try:
        the_file = open(file_name, mode)
    except IOError as e:
        print("Unable to open the file", file_name, "Ending program.\n", e)
        input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return the_file

def next_line(the_file):
    """Return next line from the trivia file, formatted."""
    line = the_file.readline()
    line = line.replace("/", "\n")
    return line

#defines block of data 
def next_block(the_file):
    """Return the next block of data from the trivia file."""
    category = next_line(the_file)
    question = next_line(the_file)

    answers = []
    for i in range(4):
        answers.append(next_line(the_file))

    correct = next_line(the_file)
    if correct:
        correct = correct[0]

    explanation = next_line(the_file)
    time.sleep(1.5)

#beginning of quiz questions

def main():
    trivia_file = open_file("trivia.txt", "r")
    title = next_line(trivia_file)
    welcome(title)
    score = 0

    # get first block
    category, question, answers, correct, explanation = next_block(trivia_file)
    while category:
        # ask a question
        print(category)
        print(question)
        for i in range(4):
            print("\t", i + 1, "-", answers[i])

        # get answer
        answer = input("What's your answer?: ")

        # check answer
        if answer == correct:
            print("\nCorrect!", end=" ")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("\nWrong.", end=" ")
        print(explanation)
        print("Score:", score, "\n\n")

        # get next block
        category, question, answers, correct, explanation = next_block(trivia_file)

    trivia_file.close()

    print("That was the last question!")
    print("Your final score is", score)


main()
```

That is most of the code associated with the program. I will be very grateful for any support available.

Comment: You will need to read in *all* the questions and their answers in one pass of the file, and then perhaps shuffle the questions (and their answers) and finally ask each question in turn. (see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file and group its contents into blocks of eight. To generate unique random questions, you can use `random.shuffle` and then list slicing to create the groups of questions. Also, it is cleaner to use a `collections.namedtuple` to form the attributes of the question for use later:

```
import random, collections
data = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')]
questions = [data[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(data), 8)]
random.shuffle(questions)
question = collections.namedtuple('question', ['category', 'question', 'answers', 'correct', 'explanation'])
final_questions = [question(*i[:2], i[2:6], *i[6:]) for i in questions]
```

Now, to create the groups of `10`:

```
group_questions = [final_questions[i:i+10] for i in range(0, len(final_questions), 10)]
```

The result will be a list of lists containing the `namedtuple` objects:

```
[[question(category='Category', question='Question', answers=['Answer', 'Answer', 'Answer', 'Answer'], correct='Correct Answer', explanation='Explanation ')]]
```

To get the desired values from each `namedtuple`, you can lookup the attributes:

```
category, question = question.category, question.question
```

Etc.