# print random from list with no duplicate

Tags: list, loops, random

I have 3 lists called animal, adjectives and group_members_b.
The group_members_b list has 5 names and need to print them out to random selcetion from animal and adjectives list.

When i use the code below i get duplicates of the name. How would i get the 5 names printed so each name is used once?

```
for i in range (0,5):
        animal = random.choice(animal_types)
        adjectives = random.choice(adjectives_list)
        name = random.choice(group_members_b)

        print (name, "is a", adjectives, animal)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shuffling a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Try to see [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm). It's used for list randomization with no repetitions.

I hope that helps.