# python randomly cycle through list

Tags: python

I have a few coordinates in my turtle graphics that I want the turtle to move between, is it possible for it to move through the list of coordinates one by one and stop at a random one?
if I do random.choice(coordinates) the turtle will just move to that coordinate, but I want it to move through the list of coordinates and stop at a randomly chosen one.

```
coordinates = ((20,-125),(50,-115),(80,-95),(100,-75),(120,-50),(130,-20),(125,20))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `shuffle` your list of coordinates :

```
from random import shuffle
coordinates = shuffle([(20,-125),(50,-115),(80,-95),(100,-75),(120,-50),(130,-20),(125,20)])
for coordinate in coordinates :
    turtle.goto(coordinate)
```

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a slice with a random number

```py
import random
coordinates = ((20,-125),(50,-115),(80,-95),(100,-75),(120,-50),(130,-20),(125,20))
coordinates_pick = coordinates[:random.randint(0,len(coordinates))]
```

Comment: He's going to iterate over all of coordinates not some of them!

Comment: Thats exaclty what the OP asked _but I want it to move through the list of coordinates and stop at a randomly chosen one._ 
The question wasn't how do I shuffle my list but rather how to stop at a random point after going through it one by one. I think this should be the correct anser

Comment: OP says : **move through the list of coordinates one by one and stop !** , So he wants to move to all of that points one by one ! shuffle will randomize all of list items so at the end turtle will stops on a random one too!

Comment: yes what I want to do is for example the pointer to move to each coordinate in the list until it stops at one random point, so like a wheel.