# How do I pop the value returned from my array?

Tags: python, arrays, function, random

So I have a function,

```
def Multiples(OGvalue, count):
    multiples = []
    for i in range(count):
        multiples.append(i*OGvalue)
    multiples.pop(1), multiples.pop(0)
    return (multiples[randrange(len(multiples))])
```

that is being called elsewhere in my program. Now, I don't want to random value that is given to repeat, so I want to remove it from my array after it is used, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Hi, perhaps shuffle might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects

Comment: You need to store the numbers that have already occurred in a global variable or class variable. But what happens when you have used all the multiples? What is the problem you are trying to solve with Multiples?