# how can I randomize the order of a list of keys and value pairs?

Tags: python, list, random, items, key-value-store

I have the following list of 12 items of paired ["key", values].
For instance the first item is: ["SN00003025", 0.1]

```
["SN00003025", 0.1], ["SN00013002", 30000.0], ["SN00037509", 23.7],
["SN00126162", 13560.0], ["SN00155812", 7.8], ["SN00232427", 3000.0], 
["SN00316328", 12.0], ["SN00319987", 5456.0], ["SN00339436", 5600.0],
["SN00399476", 12500.0], ["SN00399477", 32.0], ["SN00399478", 1100.0]
```

How can I change the order of the items of this list to random?

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects?

Comment: Thank you Krishna. I already tried that one a few days ago. I repeated it now but it does not change my list !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like `numpy.random.permutation`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html

```py
import numpy as np
lst = # ... Your list
permuted = np.random.permutation(lst)
```

Comment: good try for something new.however, the list did not change either!...???.

Comment: if I square brack the whole ist, and execute some of your code the printing add round barckets and says tuple object does not support.....

Comment: THANK YOU JACOB !. I got it to work by squaring bracketing the whole list and using import numpy as np, np.random.shuffle(mylist)..........

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

random.shuffle(my_list)
```

Comment: Thank you Jacob, but I got: TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Hey @JulioColl in that case your item must be in the format of a tuple.. is it wrapped in round brackets like this.. (1, 2, 3) or square brackets like this.. [1, 2, 3]?

Comment: Round brackets = tuple. Square brackets = list.

Comment: The whole list is not wrapped at all, only each of the pairs are wrapped by square brakets as shown above.

Comment: @JulioColl okay, wrap the whole thing in square brackets and then pass it into the random.shuffle function and it should work.

Comment: Something like: `[["SN00003025", 0.1], ["SN00013002", 30000.0], ["SN00037509", 23.7] ... ]`

Comment: @JulioColl it's my pleasure! If you found my answer helpful you can accept it by clicking the check mark below the vote tracker, thanks! :)

Comment: Yes. I will do it, except that I do not see any "vote tracker" !!! :-). Could you indicate to me where is it located?

Comment: @JulioColl by vote tracker I mean the up and down arrows in the upper left corner of every question and answer. IF you are the questioner you should also see a check mark that you can click to accept an answer.

Comment: Ok, I clicked up and check the check mark. Thanks for the info!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @JulioColl awesome, thanks! I gave you an upvote also! :) But I don't think you can vote until you have at least 15 reputation.. your almost there though!

Comment: thanks! I am still trying to figure out how the stackholder questioning works!!!. SLOWLY BUT SURELY  :-)

Comment: @JulioColl take a look at the tour page, it will help explain how things work around here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour