# Split a list randomly given chunk sizes in python

Tags: python, list, random, split, chunks

I want to write a function that returns a list of randomly splitted chunks, given a list of sizes of each chunk. For example, say I have a list of unique integers from 0 to 9

```
lst = list(range(10))
```

I want to split into 4 chunks of sizes 1, 2, 2 and 5, so the function should take an input variable `sizes` as below:

```
my_func(lst, sizes=[1, 2, 2, 5])
```

I expect the function to return something like

```
[[3], [1, 7], [2, 4], [0, 5, 6, 8, 9]]
```

If the input `sizes = [5, 1, 4]`, I expect the function to return something in order like

```
[[1, 3, 4, 6, 8], [9], [0, 2, 5, 7]]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/976882/8881141

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: okay. I think I got it after you remind me of ```random.shuffle```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach is to use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) and then go through the shuffled array!

```
import random
def my_func(lst, sizes):
    random.shuffle(lst)
    ret = []
    pointer = 0
    for s in sizes:
        ret.append(lst[pointer:pointer+s])
        pointer+=s
    return ret

lst = list(range(10))
print(my_func(lst, sizes = [1, 2, 2, 5]))
print(my_func(lst, sizes = [5, 1, 4]))
```

```
[[5], [6, 7], [4, 0], [8, 3, 9, 2, 1]]
[[5, 2, 4, 3, 0], [8], [6, 7, 9, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.shuffle` to shuffle your list. Also just keep slicing the list.

```
import random

def random_split(lst, sizes):
    if sum(sizes) != len(lst):
        raise ValueError("Sizes should match list length!")
    lst = lst.copy() # Copy list
    random.shuffle(lst) # shuffle
    res = []
    for size in sizes:
        split_list, lst = lst[:size], lst[size:] # Make two pieces of the list
        # split_list.sort()
        # Above line should be used if each sublist should be sorted
        res.append(split_list)
    return res
```

Comment: Hi mate, this is a duplicate answer!

Comment: @KuldeepSinghSidhu Not exactly both were in short succession. Honest mistake friend. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
import random

lis=[]
g_lis=[]

for i in sizes:
    list_int = i

    for j in range(list_int):
        num = random.randint(0,9)
        lis.append(num)

    g_lis.append(lis)
```