# How can I join multiple strings in not a specified order in Python?

Tags: python, random

I want to join strings but randomly.
If I do this:

```
a = 'this'
b = 'is'
c = 'a'
d = 'string'
e =  ''

f = e.join(a + b + c + d)


output : 'this is a string'
```

This is excatly what I don't want.

I want to get string in random order. Like this:

```
'string this a is'
```

Comment: So [`shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) them before you join them.

Comment: try using random.shuffle maybe

Comment: Put your strings in a list. Then this answers your question: [Shuffling a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects) `str.join()` the shuffled list.

Comment: Does shuffle works with secrets modle too?

Comment: Thank you admin for closing the post. That's definitely not what I am looking for..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of your strings and shuffle it with the shuffle function of random module.

```
import random 
random.shuffle(list)
```

Comment: What if I don't want to convert into a list?

Comment: @Szeverin and why would that be?

Comment: @Szeverin well too bad. `''.join` would *already* create a list anyway. Note, generally you don't want to use `.join` on a string

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i wanted to add that!!